# React - this.setState doesn't work as expected until function is called a second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I have a fairly basic function in my React component that isn't working as expected. The component itself is a nav bar for the top of the page. I'd like to implement a slide out menu for mobile screens triggered by a click on a hamburger icon that is inside the nav like so.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.toggleMenu.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-bars" /></a>
```

For the moment I simply have this function set up to toggle a `visible` value between `true` and `false`, which I am calling from my hamburger.

```
toggleMenu() {
    console.log('Burger clicked... ', this.state.visible);
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
    console.log('Visible changed.. ', this.state.visible); 
    var value = "A message from the burger...";
    this.props.sendData(value, this.state.visible);
  }
```

The problem is `this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });` doesn't switch from its initial value of `false` until the hamburger icon is clicked a second time.

Just for reference here is the component's constructor.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    };
  }
```

I'm relatively new to React so still finding my way around. If anyone could let me know how to resolve this issue I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

React **batches** `setState` calls to increase performance, so calculating your new state by directly accessing the old state like you are doing might not work as expected, update your `toggleMenu` like this

```
toggleMenu() {
    console.log('Burger clicked... ', this.state.visible); 
    this.setState(prevState => {
        console.log('Visible changed.. ', !prevState.visible);
        var value = "A message from the burger...";
        this.props.sendData(value, !prevState.visible);
        return  {visible: !prevState.visible };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. While this works it seems a little convoluted. Is using `prevState` the standard way to handle toggle/switch operations in React? I ask because I tried the answer from bart below, where a callback is used instead. It also works but allows me to use `this.setState.visible` with practically no other changes except for the addition of the callback. Is there any particular case why this is a bad pattern? Thanks again for the input!

Comment: **If** you calculate your new state by directly accessing the old state like you are doing, then pass a callback to the `setState` function like I did because React will batches(enqueues) multiple `setState` calls to increase the performance, so after `setState` returns, your state might not be updated **yet**. Here is the link for further reading https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information and link. It's starting to make a bit more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `this.setState()` is asynchronous. If you want something to happen after the new state is set, you'll need to include it as a callback function like so:

```
this.setState({
  visible: !this.state.visible
}, () => {
  // callback
});
```